# Templated return type specialisation for expression templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-traits, decltype

I am dealing with several kinds of expressions template and I need to know what those expressions evaluate to (eg `double`). Some of these expression templates come from 3rd party library.

I am defining the traits:

```cpp
template <typename X1>
struct EvaluatedType
```

Since I cannot specialize a template with arguments that are themselves a template ( eg `EvaluatedType<MyExpression<T>>` ), I do not specialize it but rather rely on a function `evaluate1` that I can overload (including some templated overloads):

```cpp
template <typename X1>
struct EvaluatedType
{
    using Type = decltype(evaluate1(std::declval<X1>()));
};
```

`evaluate1` cannot be a member function because it has to accept types such as `double` and support 3rd party expression template types.

The first problem I am encountering is (MWE):

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

std::string evaluate1(std::string a)
{return a;}

double evaluate1(double a)
{return a;}

template <typename X1>
struct EvaluatedType
{
    using Type = decltype(evaluate1(std::declval<X1>()));
};

int main()
{

EvaluatedType<double>::Type a;

a = 0.0;
(void) a+5.0;
}
```

This code fails to compile with:

```
error: invalid operands of types ‘void’ and ‘double’ to binary ‘operator+’
 (void) a+5.0;
```

`a` is of type `void` but I do not understand why because the return type of `evaluate1(double)` is `double`.

My other problem is that if I move the definition of `evaluate1(double)` after the definition of `EvaluatedType`, it fails to create `EvaluatedType<double>::Type` (it only sees the string version which is defined before). This is problematic because I would like other developers to be able to add new version of `evaluate1` for their expression templates and be able to use `EvaluatedType<Expr>` in other traits to know the type an expression will evaluate to.

Is there a way to define such a type:

```cpp
template <typename X1>
struct EvaluatedType;
```

in a way that `EvaluatedType<X1>::Type` will be the return type of calling `evaluate1` with argument of type `X1`.

Thank you.

Note: I have to support gcc 4.8.5 which is mostly c++11 compliant.

**Solution**

From the comments and answer, the problems are:

- (void) as precedence to + hence the error from void+double
- evaluate can only be found by ADL if not defined before EvaluatedType

Since I cannot use ADL with double, the evaluate method for double has to be defined before ResultType is defined. For the other evaluate methods, I have to make sure they are defined in the same namespace as their arguments.

```cpp
template <typename X> typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<X>::value,double>::type evaluate(const X & x)
{
    return x;
}

template <typename X>
struct EvaluatedType
{
    using Type = decltype(evaluate(std::declval<X>()));
};
```

For our expression template libraries for automatic differentiation whose expressions inherit from ScalarBase of their own type (CRTP) in namespace autodif which evaluate to xdouble (also inheriting ScalarBase) containing a double (value) + a sparse gradient vector, I then have:

```cpp
namespace autodif
{
template < typename X > xdouble evaluate(const ScalarBase<X> & x)
{
    return x; // implicitly convert with xdouble template constructor
}

} // autodif
```

Comment: "Since I cannot specialize a template with arguments that are themselves a template" why not?

Comment: `(void) a+5.0` is equivalent to `((void)a) + 5.0`, since C-style cast has higher precedence than addition.

Comment: _"This is problematic because I would like other developers to be able to add new version of evaluate1 for their expression templates and be able to use EvaluatedType in other traits to know the type an expression will evaluate to."_ I think you are about to enter the delightfully painful world of Argument Dependent Lookup. But before that, please tell us what makes you think that you can't specialize templates on classes that are themselves templates.

Comment: In the definition of your template, `evaluate1` is a dependent name. When it's called with argument type double, no ADL is performed, so only those names which are visible from the template definition context are considered. This is framed by the rule of name lookup.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. Concerning the template specialization , the syntax for specialization is ```template <> EvaluatedType<Something<T>>``` but I cannot have T be a free parameter and if I do not use template <> it will be a redefinition of the struct. My experiments with this have always failed until now, but I might be doing something wrong and I could not find an answer on how to do this online.

Comment: @felix thank you for the comment about the precedence of (void). This indeed fix the problem.

Comment: @BernardGODARD [Behold!](https://godbolt.org/z/4vUI9e) It doesn't have to be `template<>`, you can have a non-empty template argument list inside the `<` `>`.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Thank you. I did not know this was possible. But unfortunately this does not work in the following case using SFINAE: ``` template < typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,int> = 0 >
struct ResolvedType
{
    using Type = double;
};``` The error is that the number of parameters has changed. I want all native numeric types to evaluate to double.

Comment: @BernardGODARD There are two errors in there. First, it would have to be `typename  std::enable_if<...>::type = 0`, and second, it would still have to be `... ResolvedType<T>` or `... ResolvedType<Something<T>>` or similar. I don't want to patronize you for this because template metaprogramming is hard and tricky, but be aware that doing TMP around expression templates is among the hardest things you could attempt to do and may not be advisable if you are struggling with the fundamentals. PS: Block code formatting doesn't work in comments (you cannot have line breaks), use single backticks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that this is hard. We spent a long time on the expression templates implementation. They are now working. But the problem is now the interaction between the expressions and the type deduction in our other template libraries which do not understand what template parameter to use for unevaluated expressions and need to use a generic `ResolvedType<X>` to figure out what to do.

Comment: I do not want to specialize on something<T> but on T having certain properties ie being a subclass of a certain class. Hence I think the approach with the decltype(evaluate()) gives more possibilities because I can have many overloads of the evaluate method with different list of template arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(void) a+5.0;
```

this is `((void)a)+5.0;`

You want

```
(void)(a+5.0);
```

Comment: Thank you. This indeed fixes this particular problem.

Comment: @BernardGODARD You should only ask one question per question. That would avoid this awkward situation of "this fixed one of my problems but not all of them, should I accept this answer?".

Comment: @MaxLanghof And honestly, the second question is a bit obscured by the first.  As far as I can tell the code doing what the OP wants is ... well, posted by the OP.  So my guess was that once it builds, the OP may find that his code already solves the second problem.  Barring that, yes, the OP should write a [mcve] explaining what doesn't work.